# How to link a key, e.g "A", to a button?

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a game in VB and I have 4 images and 4 buttons down each image, of course right now I can click the button with the mouse to pick an option but I want to type the letter "A", "S", "D","F" of the keyboard to activate each button.

How can you do this in VB?

My current code for the button is the following

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
    My.Computer.Audio.Play ("D:\VisualStudio\DIFgame\sounds\correctSound.wav") 'correct sound audio
    Cara.Visible = True 'show face
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this windows forms?

Comment: Yes they are, so far I have 5 forms of images and buttons

Answer (score 2):

You should set the KeyPreview property ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview)) of the Form to `True`, then in the Form's KeyDown event ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown)) you would check the incoming KeyCode. If it matches one of your desired shortcuts, then raise the event of the button.

Something like:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.A) Then
        RaiseEvent Button1.Click
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David, i'm gonna try it then. Cheers

Comment: @dr.null what is wrong `KeyDown` event signature? Looking at the documentation, it appears correct.

Comment: @dr.null for simple examples I free-type the code, which is what I did here. Thank you for pointing it out to me.